# Speed up geventhttpclient's HTTPSocketPoolResponse and gevent's sock functionality in Python

Tags: uwsgi, gevent

I'm wondering if anyone has explored/deployed geventhttpclient library to their web app and, if so, had any ideas about how to further increase the speed of the HTTPSocketPoolResponse class and/or the gevent.sock.sendall() function. It's currently the most significant bottleneck in my application outside of the GET request response time from a remote server.

Side note: geventhttpclient is significantlly faster than python's standard 'requests' library (about 1/3 of the time requests was taking for my particular use case (GET request). Despite the speed enhancement, it's still a little too slow for my use case.

sock.pool takes about 0.07s 
HTTPSocketPoolResponse takes about 0.30-0.50s in local overhead (0.150-0.250s total, including the response from the remote machine) for the particular request to the web API.

My web app runs on uwsgi+nginx and runs the following during every request:

```
url = URL(req_url)
http = HTTPClient(url.host)
response = http.get(url.request_uri)
```

I was thinking moving the HTTPClient outside of the main application function and instantiate it at the start, but it failed to work.

Any pointers on how to speed up this code (socket hacks, etc.) would be helpful!

Comment: are the numbers correct? 0.150-0.250ms to make a http request to a remote server seems too good and 0.30-0.50ms seems not something you really need to optimize

Comment: Hi Tommaso, you're right-- units were supposed to be in seconds :) not milliseconds. ** This is corrected in the original post ** Still interested in knowing if there's any faster way.

Comment: Hi, you should be able to instanciate HTTP Client out of the loop. Or you will create a new connection every time. (I'm the author).